# ng zorro table with pagination

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I am having an issue ng zorr table with pagination. Uing pagination with seperate component like below

```
<nz-table #dynamicTable
                [nzScroll]="fixHeader ? { y: '240px' } : null"
                [nzData]="countryList"
                [nzLoading]="loading"
                [nzShowPagination]="false"
                [nzFooter]="footer ? 'Sayfalama' : null"
                [nzTitle]="title ? 'Müşteri Listesi' : null"
                [nzSize]="size">
        <thead>
        <tr *ngIf="header">
<!--          <th nzWidth="50px"></th>-->
          <th nzWidth="150px">Kod</th>
          <th nzWidth="70px">Ad</th>
          <th>3'lü kod</th>
          <th nzWidth="260px">Telefon kodu</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of dynamicTable.data">
<!--          <td nzShowCheckbox *ngIf="checkbox" [(nzChecked)]="data.checked"></td>-->
          <td>{{ data.code }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.tripleCode }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.phoneCode }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </nz-table>
      <br>
      <nz-pagination class="pagination" nzShowSizeChanger nzShowQuickJumper [nzTotal]="total" [(nzPageIndex)]="pageIndex" [(nzPageSize)]="pageSize"
                     (nzPageSizeChange)="pageSizeChanged($event)" (nzPageIndexChange)="pageIndexChanged($event)"
                     [nzPageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions">
      </nz-pagination>
```

The problem is when I set the total record of data which also getting it from API as below. Table show only 10 record whatever total count is.

```
loadPage() {
    this.apiService.postAny(['ListAsync'], null, this.filterModel).subscribe(data => {
      if (this.apiService.checkResponse(data)) {
        this.loading = false;
        this.total = data.result.count;
        this.countryList = [];
        this.countryList = data.result.result as CountryListModel[];
      }
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    }, () => {
      console.log('Country load completed !');
    });
  }
```

API return 17 records but table show only 10 record. If I use page navigation with page number I can see all record with page size. But If I change the directly page size (for example set it 20 per page) table only shoing 10 records nothing more. But API returns as expected.

Comment: try to add [nzPageIndex] and [nzPageSize] to <nz-table>

Answer (score 1):

"nzFrontPagination" is a property in the ng-zorro library, which is a popular open-source UI library for Angular. When this property is set to "false", it indicates that the pagination should be handled on the server side rather than on the client side. This means that when the user changes the page, the application will make a request to the server to retrieve the new set of data rather than just manipulating the data that is already loaded into the client. This is useful in situations where the data set is too large to load into the client all at once and requires pagination to be handled on the server side to improve performance and reduce load on the client. Hence you should add  `[nzFrontPagination]=false` to the nz-table element.

The full API can be found [here](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en#api)

Answer (score 0):

You need add [nzTotal] for count pages and [pageIndex], [pageSize]

Comment: Ohhh!! If you are using server side pagination

Answer (score 0):

just add [nzFrontPagination]=false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).